# SQL, delete only if exactly one row is found

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a nested query that deletes a row in table terms only if exactly one row in definitions.term_id is found. It works but it takes like 9 seconds on my system. Im looking to optimize the query.

```
DELETE FROM terms 
WHERE id 
IN(
    SELECT term_id 
    FROM definitions 
    WHERE term_id = 1234 
    GROUP BY term_id 
    HAVING COUNT(term_id) = 1
    )
```

The database is only about 4000 rows. If I separate the query into 2 independent queries, it takes about 0.1 each

**terms**

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| term  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**definitions**

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| term_id        | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| definition     | varchar(500)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| example        | varchar(500)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| submitter_name | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| approved       | int(1)           | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| created_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| votos          | int(3)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

To speed up the process, please consider creating an index on the relevant field:

```
CREATE INDEX term_id ON terms (term_id)
```

Comment: I think you mean to create the index on the `definitions` table rather than `terms` (though the tables weren't explicitly named until after you posted this). It will reduce the reads required to do the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

How about using correlated sub query using `exists` and try,

```
DELETE FROM terms t
WHERE id = 1234
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM definitions d
               WHERE d.term_id = t.term_id 
               GROUP BY term_id 
               HAVING COUNT(term_id) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often quicker to create a new table retaining only the rows you wish to keep. That said, I'd probably write this as follows, and provide indexes as appropriate.

```
DELETE 
  FROM terms t
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT term_id 
          FROM definitions 
         WHERE term_id = 1234 
         GROUP 
            BY term_id 
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
      ) x
    ON x.term_id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hehe; this may be a kludgy way to do it:

```
DELETE ... WHERE id = ( SELECT ... )
```

but *without* any `LIMIT` or other constraints.

I'm depending on getting an error something like "subquery returned more than one row" in order to prevent the `DELETE` being performed if multiple rows match.